# Generating function with a given weight function using 3 variables

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

So I'm given a set: [10] x [2] x $\mathbb N$ with a weight function: $w(a, b, c) = 4a + 2b + c$

And i'm asked to determine the generating series of this, but I'm confused due to the 3 variables..

I understand that $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n $ and that $a_n$ is the number of $(a, b, c)$ such that $n = 4a + 2b + c$. But I'm confused as to how I would get this, given the set.

Would this be acceptable for example?

We can pick $a\in{1, 2, 3, ... , 10}$ so that there are 10 possibilities of this. Then $b$ only has two possibilities (since it's either 1 or 2), so there are now 20 possibilities where $c$ is fixed at $c = n - 4a - 2b$. But where would I go from here?

EDIT --- adding on to Brain M. Scott's answer:

picking $a\in[10]$ gives me

$$x^4+x^8+\ldots+x^{40}=\sum_{a\in[10]}x^{4a} = \frac{1-(x^4)^{11}}{1-x^4}.$$ by geometric series.

$b\in[2]$ gives me

$$x^2+x^4=\sum_{b\in[2]}x^{2b}$$

and $c\in\mathbb N$ gives

$$x+x^2+x^3+\ldots=\sum_{c\in\Bbb N}x^c\; = \frac{x}{1-x}$$

I removed the $1$ at the beginning since this set excludes $0$.

So I multiplied these 3, giving me:

${x^3+x^5-x^{45}-x^{49}}\over{1-x-x^4+x^5}$

Would this be my final rational expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that you were just picking $a\in[10]$; then your series would be

$$x^4+x^8+\ldots+x^{40}=\sum_{a\in[10]}x^{4a}\;.$$

Similarly, $b$ would give you

$$x^2+x^4=\sum_{b\in[2]}x^{2b}\;,$$

and $c$ would give you

$$1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots=\sum_{c\in\Bbb N}x^c\;.$$

What happens if you multiply those three series together?

Comment: Please see my above edit.

Comment: @E46: Almost: the first numerator should be $x^4-(x^4)^{11}$, since there’s no $a=0$ term. The rest is fine, assuming that for you $\Bbb N$ doesn’t include $0$. (For me it does; if I want the positive integers, I use $\Bbb Z^+$.)

Comment: It was specified, unless it's $\mathbb N_0$, then it does not include 0 (with respect to my textbook). But would the multiplying of the different generating series specifically for each term be acceptable because the set is a Cartesian product?

Comment: @E46: Yes: the choices of $a,b$, and $c$ are independent, so you can combine them in any way, and taking the product does just that: before you collect terms, the product gives you one term for each combination of possible $a,b$, and $c$.

Comment: That makes much more sense! Thank you so much.

Comment: @E46: You’re very welcome.